# From joint to conditional probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I found the following expression in a paper but I'm not quite sure where does it come from:

let $Y$ and $V$ be two random variables defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and with support respectively $\mathcal{Y}$ and $\mathcal{V}$, both compact sets. Let $M \subset \mathcal{Y}\times \mathcal{V}$. Hence,
$$
\mathbb{P}((Y,V) \in M)=\int_{\mathcal{t \in V}} \mathbb{P}(Y \in M_t| V=t)\mathbb{P}_V(dt) \hspace{1cm}\text{(*)}
$$
where $M_t:=\{k \in \mathcal{Y}:(k,t) \in M \text{ $k$ singleton} \}$. I don't understand equation (*) and, in particular, what $\mathbb{P}_V(dt)$ is.

Comment: Your $P_V(dV)$ should read $P_V(dt)$.

Comment: Correction made, thanks, but (*) is still obscure to me..

Comment: Then $P_V$ is the distribution of $V$ hence $\int C(t)P_V(dt)=E(C(V))$ for every function $C$ and the identity in your post is exactly the definition of the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditionally on $V$.

Comment: Still unclear, sorry: in (*) on the lhs there is the joint distribution of Y and V. Can you explain better why according to you the rhs is equivalent to the lhs?

Comment: Might try to see what happens when M is a product. (The mention "according to me" is irrelevant.)